# How to concat two columns from SQL Server using knex.js without using knex.raw()

Tags: sql, node.js, distinct, concatenation, knex.js

I have here a sample code.

Can someone translate this to knex without using `knex.raw`?

```
SELECT DISTINCT (columna + '-' + columnb) AS column 
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

knex has [distinct](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-distinct)

```
const rows = await knex('table').distinct('columna', 'columnb')
rows.map(row => `${columna}-${columnb}`)
```